# Why are vector mesons identified by the adjective vector?

Tags: particle-physics

[vector mesons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_meson) are

> mesons with total spin 1 and odd parity (usually noted as JP = 1−). Compare to a pseudovector meson, which has a total spin 1 and even parity.

coming from a mathematics background, this is confusing; what is 'vectorish' about a vector meson? My guess would be that this may be something to do with the way that particles are identified as irreducible representations of a group, and this would involve them being represented on a vector space - is this in the right ball-park?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the spin-1 that makes it a vector.  The spin-1 representation of the Lorentz group (more precisely, the $\left( \frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2} \right)$ representation) transforms like a four-vector under Lorentz transformations.  This is why the vector potentials $A^\mu$ have a single Lorentz index.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representation_theory_of_the_Lorentz_group#Common_representations for more information.

Comment: Ok, this is where my mathematical training makes this confusing; a representation of a group is on a vector space, so all representations ought to 'transform as a vector'; from what you say, it looks as though - using mathematical language - its a representation of the Lorentz group that can't be lifted to the double (or universal) cover of the Lorentz group - so its not a 'spinorial' representation; but what it probably means is I should learn physics language as physicists use it. Thanks for your explanation.

Comment: Yes, that's correct, it's not a spinorial representation.  You're right that when physicists talk about "vectors" and "scalars" they shamelessly fail to distinguish between the linear algebra senses of the words (where the scalars are the field of numbers by which you can multiply the vectors) and the Lorentz transformation senses of the words, and in the context of QFT often use both simultaneously.  When people talk about "vector mesons" they're only talking about how the representation transforms under Lorentz transformations - a notion completely unrelated to the fact that they're ...

Comment: ...quantum operators.

Comment: ok, thanks; that clears up quite a bit of confusion for me

Comment: @MoziburUllah Want to give me the check mark? ;)

Comment: you've got the tick!